# Derivative of the Solution to a transcendental equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on a physics problem so if the notation isn't exact please forgive me, but I have the following math question.

I solve the transcendental equation below for a given i:
$$0 = \Delta M - C_1\rho_s(i,M^\star) + C_2\Delta M^2 + C_3 \Delta M^3 \\
\Delta M = (M-M^\star)$$
Where $C_1,C_2,C_3$ and $M$ are all constants, the value that I want is $M^\star$ (an effective mass), and
$$\rho_S(i) = \sum_{j \neq i} \frac{M^{\star}(j)}{E(j)} \exp{\bigg(-\frac{(\vec{r}(i) - \vec{r}(j))^2}{\mathcal{A}}\bigg)}$$
With $(\vec{r}(i) - \vec{r}(j))^2$ being a quick way of denoting the distance in 3D space between two points $\vec{r}(i) = (x(i),y(i),z(i))$  and $\vec{r}(j) = (x(j),y(j),z(j))$
What I then need to do is derive the forces from my Hamiltonian that has the following form :
$$\text{H}(i) =\frac{g_v^2}{2m_v^2} \rho_B(i)^2+\frac{m_s^2}{2g_s^2}\Delta M^2 + \dots $$
*Here the $\rho_B$ is not dependent on $M^\star$*

But this requires that I be able to do the following :
$$\frac{\partial \Delta M^2}{\partial x} = 2 \Delta M \frac{\partial \Delta M}{\partial x}=2 \Delta M ({\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}} - \frac{\partial M^\star}{\partial x} )=-2 \Delta M \frac{\partial M^\star}{\partial x} $$

How do I derive a value for the derivative of $M^\star$ if it does not have an explicit equation ?